# Is this a race condition in go

Tags: go, race-condition

```
func main() {
    m := map[string]int{
        "foo": 42,
        "bar": 1337,
    }

    go func() {
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
        tmp := map[string]int{
            "foo": 44,
            "bar": 1339,
        }

        m = tmp
    }()

    for {
        val := m["foo"]
        fmt.Println(val)
    }
}
```

I saw this in many packages.

Why this is not considered as a race condition?

`go run -race .` giving no error.

Comment: This is a data race. If the race detector detects a data race you have a data race. But the race detector doesn't detect all data races; I'm unsire why it doesn't detect this one. Using the race detector gives you just one-sided information: If data race reported then you have one. If non is reported you know nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by @Volker, this is a data race. And since there is only one write, it's hard to be detected. Here is a modified demo to make it easy to trigger the data race error:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    m := map[string]int{
        "foo": 42,
        "bar": 1337,
    }

    done := make(chan any)

    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
            time.Sleep(time.Microsecond)
            tmp := map[string]int{
                "foo": 44,
                "bar": 1339,
            }

            m = tmp
        }

        close(done)
    }()

    for {
        select {
        case <-done:
            return
        default:
            val := m["foo"]
            fmt.Println(val)
        }
    }
}
```